# XNA - .dll game library crashes on start

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dll, xna, xna-4.0

I am trying to make an XNA game library that compiles into dll file. 
When I add this library to game solution and add a project reference, everything is working great. When I try to directly reference generated .dll file game crashes on start with output message:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.dll

(when I run it with project reference, information about my .dll being loaded is displayed instead)

I am unable to set any breakpoints or write to log, game seems to crash before it is even started.

After long search I found that this can happen if one does not set "Copy Local" value to True, but I do have is set..

I appreciate any help, thank you.

**Edit:**

This is just beyond my comprehension, but it seems that problem was caused by RENAMING a .dll file.. When I keep original name (I guess maching project name or whatever) it works... Anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: Are you compiling your dll as x86, x64 or AnyCPU?

Comment: Where exactly is your library DLL stored, and what is the exact path string you're using to access it? Also, what is the full text of the exception? Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: William, I should have mentioned this is Windows Phone 7 project, I guess x86 is only option there.
@TarkaDaal , DLL is stored in project directory (in a folder placed next to .sln file). I added this DLL by Visual's option 'Add Reference' and browsing to file, when I check reference's propeties, path is an absolute one.

Unfortunately this error is all I got, I am unable to do a stack trace as game is automaticly closing, rather than stopping on error and allowing debug.

Comment: @Shadarath : What are the actual paths? Are you running your code in an emulator, with PC as the target, or on the actual phone? Put some debug code in your application and get more information on the exception.

Comment: @TarkaDaal precise path is:
C:\DANE\WP7_TOOLS\TEMPLATES\Libs\PlsftHelperDebug.dll

I am running on actual phone. Putting debuging code in application does not help as it seems app is not even reaching first line of Game's constructor.

Comment: @Shadarath : That path looks as if it is on your development computer, not on the phone. How are you copying the DLL to the phone? What path do you use to specify it on the phone? If it can't find the DLL, then yes - it will be crashing very early on. Is your Game class defined in the DLL? Try wrapping your Main() method in a try catch as described here : http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/adventures-in-unhandled-exception-handling-for-xnasilverlight/ Remember to log the exception information in an appropriate manner for Windows Phone (e.g. no Console.WriteLine or similar).

Comment: You need to determine what is causing the exception, and despite your claims this cannot be done, it actually can be done.  Without this information we cannot guide you to a solution, we certainly cannot do it without code, which you didn't provide.

Comment: @TarkaDaal, I was not copying it by myself at all, as it was supposed to be automaticly included in .xap file that is deployed onto phone.
Note, that on Windows Phone there is no traditional Main function that is calling Run() method on Game class - that is only the case for Windows and Xbox. On WP7 there is event that can be registered to, to get all unhandled exceptions (as described in your link) but I was unable to use it at it crashed before I could even register to event.. If there is another way to catch such exceptions, I lack knowledge to do so.

Comment: Also, @Ramhound I did not provide code, because I believed it is not connected to this particular case - it was crashing before it even reached my code.

I finaly found a solution to my problem - see an update in question. I do not understand why it works this way, but well, it works.

Thank you for all your help.